# Process.ExitCode is always 0 if ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput is true

Tags: c#

Given the following code, I cannot seem to get a valid Process.ExitCode -- it is always 0 if TraceOutput is set.  TraceOutput enables Stdout/Stderr capturing.  If I set TraceOutput to false, the exit code comes out correctly every time:

```
    protected ScanResult ExecuteScan(ProcessStartInfo processInfo)
    {
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.ErrorDialog = false;            
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        if (TraceOutput)
        {
            processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        }

        using (var process = new Process())
        {
            process.StartInfo = processInfo;

            // setup events to capture output, if tracing
            if (TraceOutput)
            {
                process.OutputDataReceived += OutputDataReceived;
                process.ErrorDataReceived += ErrorDataReceived;                   
            }

            // actually start the process
            Trace.TraceInformation("Running scan: {0} {1}", processInfo.FileName, processInfo.Arguments);
            process.Start();

            // actually capture output, if tracing
            if (TraceOutput)
            {
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();
            }

            // wait for the timeout, if supplied
            bool finished;
            if (Timeout == System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
            {
                process.WaitForExit();
                finished = process.HasExited;
            }
            else finished = process.WaitForExit(Timeout);

            // handle timeout expiry, by logging and marking as unknown
            if (!finished)
            {
                Trace.TraceWarning("Scan timed out after {0:#,0} milliseconds", Timeout);

                try
                {
                    if (TraceOutput)
                    {
                        process.CancelOutputRead();
                        process.CancelErrorRead();
                    }

                    if (!process.HasExited) 
                        process.Kill();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Trace.TraceWarning("{0} thrown while cleaning up scan process - {0}",
                                       ex.GetType().Name,
                                       ex.Message);
                }

                return ScanResult.Unknown;
            }

            if (TraceOutput)
            {
                process.CancelOutputRead();
                process.CancelErrorRead();
            }

            // flush all output and gather exit code
            do
            {
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
            while (!process.HasExited);

            // if we exit with a valid success code, this is a successful scan
            var exitCode = process.ExitCode;
            var hasSuccessCode = (Array.IndexOf(SuccessExitCodes, exitCode) != -1);

            return hasSuccessCode
                       ? ScanResult.Ok
                       : ScanResult.Failed;
        }
    }

    private static void OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Data))
            Trace.WriteLine(e.Data, "        :: Scan Stdout");
    }
    private static void ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Data))
            Trace.WriteLine(e.Data, "        :: Scan Stderr");
    }

// later...
SuccessExitCodes = new[] { 0 };
TraceOutput = true // TraceOutput is a property defined elsewhere...
var result = ExecuteScan(new ProcessStartInfo("myApp.exe", "args"));
```

I thought I'd read the various MSDN clauses about having to call WaitForExit without arguments, in case of a race condition with the asynchronous methods but, having done that, it still returns `0`.

What am I missing...?

Comment: Is it possible that the program you're executing behaves differently when it detects output redirection? You could try executing a program that always immediately exits with code 100 (or something) to validate your code.

Comment: Are you sure the exit code is 0, or are you determining that in a roundabout way by the result of this code: `var hasSuccessCode = (Array.IndexOf(SuccessExitCodes, exitCode) != -1); return hasSuccessCode ? ScanResult.Ok : ScanResult.Failed;`? I.e., probably show us the code for `SuccessExitCodes`.

Comment: @Quantic - yes, sorry. SuccessExitCodes is just a property that currently returns int[] { 0 }

Comment: @Blorgbeard - good point, I'll check in the morning

Comment: @Blorgbeard - When run from the command-line and redirecting both stdout and stderr to a file (i.e. `myApp.exe args >c:\temp\spool.txt 2>&1`) the resulting `%ERRORLEVEL%` is set to non-zero, as expected, so I don't *think* it's a foible of the app.

Comment: @downvoter - care to comment?

Comment: I tried your code running against a program that just prints one line to stdout, one to stderr, then returns 1 from main. It successfully reported the return code with Trace on (and off).

Comment: @Blorgbeard - I think you're probably right about detecting output redirection.  I can't prove it by redirecting in the command prompt (and I don't know of other ways to redirect), but it does hold as the most likely.  I've triggered other apps using this code, and it has worked fine -- just must be specific to this one.  Feel free to post as an answer, and I'll accept...